# Nunit3 testing Android xamarin cannot output text

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin, nunit

I have created an NUnit test for my android application and I was expecting to see some text outputted.

Am I missing the obvious? How do you output text in result?

```
  [Test]
    public void ConsoleWriteline_WhenInvokedWithText_Does_NotOutputText()
    {
        System.Console.Write("foo"); //does not work
        System.Console.WriteLine("bar");//does not work

        Assert.Pass("Test");
    }
```

Comment: Try Trace.Write or Debug.Write

Comment: thanks for your answer they show in the output window but do not appear in the unit test

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious thing that you are missing is called standards. :)

1. The expected and the actual values are what a test focuses on, if the two 
   are same then there is no output of values; if not, they are displayed 
   (except in type difference or object references)
2. The [Description] attribute can output any text you want
3. This is related to unit test standards.

   An assert is the equivalent of a console.write. Assertion is the only 
   feedback mechanism that you should look for from a unit test and not
   subjective text messages because a unit test's purpose is just that

   - to give an objective feedback on the behavior of the code.
4. All unit test frameworks output the same way.

Is there some specific purpose that a text output would serve the test? If yes, please mention here what the purpose is.

Comment: I appreciate that you took time in writing a reply,but let me tell you something,I have been doing TDD for quite a while and worked in different teams and this is a new one,I am fairly new to xamarin world though. What you said is very patronising and not helpful in the least. I come from a background of clean code and pure unit tests and all that agile stuff that comes with it, if fact to an extreme that I dont like ,that is why I changed job. Yes there is a purpose and it's because my new collegues find it helpful and they have this thing that they also ouput other stuff apart from asserts

Comment: @developer9969 - sorry if you took it as patronizing but if you read carefully, it answers your question as you have asked it. Let me know which part of my comment is patronizing and I will edit it.